# Ler uma frase especifica de um arquivo e parar nele

Tags: c, string, matriz, array

Quero armazenar em um *string* uma parte de um arquivo:
Bruno Mossa Rezende         5   2   7   6   22  22  0.13    8   19  141 0.17    260 2   320 5.42    43  22  6   0.90    0   0   5

desse arquivo quero armazenar em uma *string* "Bruno Mossa Rezende", não quero os números no momento, quero saber como fazer parar nessa parte, ou um meio para fazer isso se possível, por favor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

}
```

---

no arquivo .txt tem isso aqui:

```
15
Bruno Mossa Rezende         5   2   7   6   22  22  0.13    8   19  141 0.17    260 2   320 5.42    43  22  6   0.90    0   0   5
Douglas Souza               22  12  23  4   5   8   0.08    1   10  25  0.02    0   0   4   0.00    25  7   1   0.52    49  10  22
Eder Carbonera              30  6   19  15  44  19  0.31    9   16  75  0.19    0   0   3   0.00    14  9   1   0.28    5   3   2
Evandro M. Guerra           50  14  27  7   17  13  0.15    1   5   17  0.02    0   0   1   0.00    10  5   2   0.21    0   0   0
Isac Santos             31  8   8   7   20  14  0.15    1   14  44  0.02    0   0   3   0.00    3   2   1   0.06    0   0   0
Lucas Saatkamp              58  9   21  8   30  23  0.17    9   23  62  0.19    0   0   3   0.00    13  2   1   0.27    2   0   1
Luiz Felipe Marques Fonteles        27  7   17  4   14  8   0.08    3   7   41  0.06    0   0   3   0.00    19  9   2   0.40    40  8   33
Mauricio Borges Almeida Silva       80  20  54  3   28  21  0.06    11  18  68  0.23    0   0   4   0.00    28  20  4   0.57    93  22  83
Maurício Souza              46  5   22  28  41  26  0.57    5   11  109 0.10    0   0   3   0.00    13  5   2   0.27    2   1   3
Murilo Endres               14  4   22  2   7   6   0.04    4   7   16  0.08    0   0   4   0.00    12  9   0   0.25    30  0   28
Ricardo Lucarelli Santos De Souza   135 36  74  9   21  14  0.19    23  28  131 0.48    0   0   15  0.00    64  19  4   1.33    97  13  102
Sérgio Dutra Santos         0   0   1   0   0   0   0.00    0   0   0   0.00    0   2   26  0.00    52  23  4   1.08    55  19  46
Tiago Brendle               0   0   0   0   0   1   0.00    0   0   0   0.00    0   0   8   0.00    44  16  7   0.92    46  5   29
Wallace De Souza            160 40  90  23  32  32  0.48    8   25  91  0.17    1   0   8   0.02    43  24  8   0.90    0   1   0
William Arjona              1   0   0   0   5   8   0.00    1   2   54  0.02    92  0   118 1.92    21  10  2   0.44    0   0   1
```

---

preciso saber como pegar os nomes e guardá-los em uma *string* e os numero em vetores ou matrizes, o meu objetivo é apresentar rankings e notas totais, e para isso preciso pegar os valores corretamente para fazer isso. Alguém por favor quando começar a fazer o código fonte coloque as bibliotecas e se é `int main ()`, ou outro por favor agradeço.

Comment: E o que você já fez? Qual sua dúvida específica?

Answer (score 0):

Tem um jeito de fazer isso usando o `fscanf` em conjunto com o `strlen`. Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
char buffer[/* coloque um tamanho razoável aqui*/];
char *ptr = buffer;
while (fscanf(file, "%s", ptr))
{
    ptr += strlen(ptr);
    *(ptr++) = ' ';
}
*(--ptr) = 0; // ptr agora aponta para o final da frase
              // buffer pode ser usado como uma string normal
```

Como esse código funciona? Repare que `ptr` sempre aponta para dentro do `buffer` (cuidado que esse código é suscetível a overflow). Quando esse `fscanf` ler uma palavra dentro do `file`, ele vai armazenar no `buffer` a partir do ponto salvo pelo `ptr` e retorna 1. Se ele conseguir ler a palavra, o `ptr` é atualizado para depois da palavra e um espaço é adicionado, permitindo assim armazenar a próxima palavra. Depois que todas as palavras são lidas, ele retorna 0 e o ponto de execução sai do `while`. Por fim, como a última iteração adiciona um espaço extra no final da frase, o último espaço é retirado.